# Zsh autocompleting cd with other people's home directories

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Found this weird behavior with zsh autocompletion for cd. For some reason, if I write the prefix of a username after cd and press tab it will autocomplete to username/ and try to cd to that user's home directory when I press enter. I.e.,

```
/some/random/path/$ cd ler<TAB>
```

This will auto complete to

```
/some/random/path/$ cd leroy/
```

When I press enter it tries to cd to `/home/leroy`.

How do I disable this?
I haven't done anything fancy with autocomplete config. `CDPATH` is just ".", and this is what zstyle tells me about cd

```
$ zstyle | grep -w cd
    :completion:*:cd:* local-directories directory-stack path-directories
```

If I change that to just `local-directories` strange behavior does not go away.

Comment: Is the shell option "cdablevars" enabled?

Comment: @Adaephon, indeed it was! Thank you, that fixed. Really don't understand why you'd want this behavior.